# Resizing by mouse the rest of images in a row after resizing a one, and keep ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I am using [jQuery ui Resizable](https://api.jqueryui.com/resizable)

After the resizing, all images should update both: their height and their width. But for the images that are not actually resized by a user, only the height is being updated. So the images are getting distorted. How to improve my code to maintain the ratio of all images while resizing?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.outer {
  border: red dashed 2px;
  position: relative;
}
.ui-wrapper, .member {
  display: inline-block;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.member, .ui-wrapper {
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <img class="res image member" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x50" alt="" />
  <img class="res image member" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50" alt="" />
  <img class="res image member" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50" alt="" />
</div>
<script>
$(".res").resizable({
    aspectRatio: true,
    ghost: true,
    stop: function( event, ui) {
  height=ui.size.height;
  $(".ui-wrapper, .member").height(height + "px");
}});
</script>
```

### EDIT

Code Snippet doesn't work, so I add a screenshot before and after the resizing:

[image]

After the resizing of the middle image:

[image]

### EDIT2

And a demo:

https://codepen.io/trzczy/pen/PozyVjV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.outer {
  border: red dashed 2px;
}
.ui-wrapper, .member {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

js:

```
$(".res").resizable({
    aspectRatio: true,
    // ghost: true,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      height=ui.size.height;
    // $(".ui-wrapper, .member").height(height + "px");
      $(".ui-wrapper, .member").each(function() {
            ratio = height / $(this).height();
        console.log(parseInt($(this).height() * ratio, 10));
            $(this).css("height", parseInt($(this).height() * ratio, 10));
            $(this).css("width", parseInt($(this).width() * ratio, 10));
      });
    }
});
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/trzczy/pen/XWKQbVQ)